# How to store data when in Deactivated Event for Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

When user click the Bing Search button, this will cause Deactivated event. So, I have these questions.

1) When user press Bing Search Button, How to I store the data. What type of Data can be stored and What to use to  store?

How do I store stream type data?

2) When user Click Back Button after pressing Bing Search Button,  this will reActivate ? What event will this be and  How do I get back the data that I store in (1)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jeff Prosise's Real-World Tombstoning in Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 will tell you everything you need to know about tombstoning:

- [Part 1](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/02/04/real-world-tombstoning-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-part-1.aspx)
- [Part 2](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/02/04/real-world-tombstoning-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-part-2.aspx)
- [Part 3](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/02/04/real-world-tombstoning-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-part-3.aspx)
- [Part 4](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/02/07/real-world-tombstoning-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-part-4.aspx)

Comment: Thank Q thank Q. IT is so useful and it explains the tombstonning in a simple and easy way to understand.